# Extracting data from RDD in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

So I have a large dataset that is a sample of a stackoverflow userbase. One line from this dataset is as follows:

```
<row Id="42" Reputation="11849" CreationDate="2008-08-01T13:00:11.640" DisplayName="Coincoin" LastAccessDate="2014-01-18T20:32:32.443" WebsiteUrl="" Location="Montreal, Canada" AboutMe="A guy with the attention span of a dead goldfish who has been having a blast in the industry for more than 10 years.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Mostly specialized in game and graphics programming, from custom software 3D renderers to accelerated hardware pipeline programming." Views="648" UpVotes="337" DownVotes="40" Age="35" AccountId="33" />
```

I would like to extract the number from reputation, in this case it is "11849" and the number from age, in this example it is "35" I would like to have them as floats.

The file is located in a HDFS so it comes in the format RDD

```
 val linesWithAge = lines.filter(line => line.contains("Age="))    //This is filtering data which doesnt have age
    val repSplit = linesWithAge.flatMap(line => line.split("\"")) //Here I am trying to split the data where there is a "
```

so when I split it with quotation marks the reputation is in index 3 and age in index 23 but how do I assign these to a map or a variable so I can use them as floats.
Also I need it to do this for every line on the RDD.

EDIT:

```
   val linesWithAge = lines.filter(line => line.contains("Age="))    //transformations from the original input data
   val repSplit = linesWithAge.flatMap(line => line.split("\""))
    val withIndex = repSplit.zipWithIndex
    val indexKey = withIndex.map{case (k,v) => (v,k)}
    val b = indexKey.lookup(3)
    println(b)
```

So if added an index to the array and now I've successfully managed to assign it to a variable but I can only do it to one item in the RDD, does anyone know how I could do it to all items?

Comment: You're looking for the `map` function. A quick search brought this example up: http://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-map-example/

Comment: Map function with what function as parameter? I want to collect the index at 3 and at 23 for each line in the dataset. Please can you give an example as I've tried using the map function already.

Comment: A function that takes an array and produces a tuple of two numbers: `f: Array[String] => (Int, Int)` Maybe you could give it a try? If you don't know how to do that yet, there're many learning resources.

Comment: can you check the edit I made please @maasg

Comment: Did you check the result of those operations? What kind of results do you get?

Comment: you should use map. This should give you sufficient guidance: https://gist.github.com/maasg/d2d198efd70ae9226b7da916a8e709f4

Comment: Thanks for your help i can see how thats a better implementation, but i still dont know what to replace the "???" with i though about adding .split("Reputation=") but wouldnt that give be two things inside the val. Im really sorry to keep asking but I have no knowledge of scala or spark @maasg

Comment: Why do you have to do this, then? Sure we can help with this, but you'll probably face a new issue in the very next step.

Comment: I provided an answer below. I'm still interested to know why you have to do this task (for academic purposes)

Answer (score 1):

What we want to do is to transform each element in the original dataset (represented as an RDD) into a tuple containing `(Reputation, Age)` as numeric values.

One possible approach is to transform each element of the RDD using String operations in order to extract the values of the elements "Age" and "Reputation", like this:

```
// define a function to extract the value of an element, given the name
def findElement(src: Array[String], name:String):Option[String] = {
  for {
    entry <- src.find(_.startsWith(name))
    value <- entry.split("\"").lift(1)
  } yield value
}
```

We then use that function to extract the interesting values from every record:

```
val reputationByAge = lines.flatMap{line => 
    val elements = line.split(" ")
    for {
        age <- findElement(elements, "Age")
        rep <- findElement(elements, "Reputation")
    } yield (rep.toInt, age.toInt)
}
```

Note how we don't need to filter on "Age" before doing this. If we process a record that does not have "Age" or "Reputation", `findElement` will return `None`. Henceforth the result of the `for-comprehension` will be `None` and the record will be *flattened* by the `flatMap` operation.

A better way to approach this problem is by realizing that we are dealing with structured XML data. Scala provides built-in support for XML, so we can do this:

```
import scala.xml.XML
import scala.xml.XML._

// help function to map Strings to Option where empty strings become None 
def emptyStrToNone(str:String):Option[String] = if (str.isEmpty) None else Some(str)

val xmlReputationByAge = lines.flatMap{line => 
    val record = XML.loadString(line)
    for {          
      rep <- emptyStrToNone((record \ "@Reputation").text)
      age <- emptyStrToNone((record \ "@Age").text)
    } yield (rep.toInt, age.toInt)
}
```

This method relies on the structure of the XML record to extract the right attributes. As before, we use the combination of `Option` values and `flatMap` to remove records that do not contain all the information we require.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need a function which extracts the value for a given key of your line (`getValueForKeyAs[T]`), then do:

```
val rdd = linesWithAge.map(line => (getValueForKeyAs[Float](line,"Age"), getValueForKeyAs[Float](line,"Reputation")))
```

This should give you an rdd of type `RDD[(Float,Float)]`

`getValueForKeyAs` could be implemented like this:

```
def getValueForKeyAs[A](line:String, key:String) : A = {
    val res = line.split(key+"=")
    if(res.size==1) throw new RuntimeException(s"no value for key $key")
    val value = res(1).split("\"")(1)
    return value.asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

Comment: break a program with a `RuntimeException` because we don't find a key? I don't think I would do that. Returning an `Option` type would be a much better alternative.

Comment: Then feel free to provide your own answer. I think in this case I would prefer an Exception bechause I know I only process lines which contains the desired keys. If the keys are not present, then this is a programming fault, and this case a RuntimeException justified...

Comment: If the keys are not present, it's incomplete data, something that's happens all the time.